Почему нет корня «-ём-»?
Почему в таких словах, как подъём, разъём, съём, приём, объём, проём, корен — это всё слово? Там же, отчётно видно, есть общая часть ём, использующаяся с различными приставками, отчего подчас возникает ъ.

приставка заканчивается на согласную?

ААа, это бадяга что типа корень "приём"? - нет корень во всех этих словах ём, а что-то большее, это то ли "корневое гнездо", то ли "корневой формант" по Тихонову, мы это выяснили. Это какие-то кульбиты современной лингвистики, которые перепутали названия и делают вид, что все ок.

@Буратино Здесь немного другая история, то есть другой принцип для определения связанного корня.  Обычно мы делаем именно РАЗБОР корня, то есть последовательно разбираем целое слово на части. Что останется, то и корень. Здесь же корень определяется иначе, а именно путем сравнения пар: одеть – раздеть. И опять два уровня: школьный и вузовский. Но здесь  в школе выделяется корневой формант приставка + корень, а вузовский вариант – без приставки.

Еще интересное слово "емкий".  Разбор: Корень: -ём -; суффикс: -к; окончание: -ий [Тихонов, 1996].   Развязался у них, что ли, корень?))

@Sharon не знаю при чём тут школа, когда очевидно, что корень ём-ем, ну может ещё *им-ым-ним связанное, и *мест. Зачем создавать бессвязную путаницу, кроме как запутать окончательно, не понятно. Может у них фетиш какой-то на приставки? ну откажитесь тогда совсем от понятия "приставка" чего уж там...


Подъём, разъём, съём, приём, объём, проём — в этих словах вязанный корень ем. Но разбор слов неоднозначный и имеет варианты: можно выделять приставку, а можно нет.

В школе легче не выделять приставки, и более упрощенным является следующий разбор: корень подъем + нулевое окончание. Он приводится в словаре Тихонова.

Интересен разбор слова раздеть (там тоже связанный корень): раз/де/ть. Поэтому решения непоследовательные.

Ответ Грамоты №307439
Какой корень в слове "подъем"? Наша учительница утверждает, что "под" — это приставка. ОТВЕТ
В слове подъём можно выделить приставку под- и корень -ём-. Приставка в слове имеет свойственное ей значение направленности действия, движения снизу вверх. Корень -ём- выделяется при сравнении со словами разъем, отъем (от отнять). В корне происходит чередование, ср.: поднять — поднимать — подъем.


О связанных корнях
Алгоритм морфемного членения основы
Процесс определения морфемного состава через словообразовательную цепочку не начинается с выделения корня, а заканчивается им. Со слова как бы «снимаются» аффиксы; то, что осталось, — корень.
Единственное исключение из этой закономерности — слова со связанными корнями. Связанным, как уже было сказано, является корень, который не употребляется самостоятельно, то есть только с формообразующими морфемами, а всегда встречается в соединении со словообразующими приставками и суффиксами, причём может присоединять к себе различные хорошо вычленяющиеся приставки и / или суффиксы.
Разбор таких слов осуществляется через построение морфемных квадратов , в которых данный корень должен быть употреблён с другим суффиксом (приставкой), а суффикс (приставка) — с другим корнем: об‑у‑ть – раз‑у‑ть, о‑де‑ть – раз‑де‑ть.

За что боролись, на то и напоролись, "рукалицо"...
